# enable novalidate

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ALTER TABLE EMP ADD ( CONSTRAINT CC_NAME CHECK (TRIM(TRANSLATE(UPPER(ename),' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_,.',' ')) is null)) enable novalidate;
```

not working 10g i got

> ORA-00905: missing keyword

Please help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Remove parenthesis after `ADD` (if you want to add just one CONSTRAINT):

```
ALTER TABLE EMP 
ADD CONSTRAINT CC_NAME CHECK (TRIM(TRANSLATE(UPPER(ename),' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_,.',' ')) is null) 
enable novalidate;
```

More info [ALTER TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm)

**EDIT:**

If you want to add more constraints at once use:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD  (
     CONSTRAINT constraint_1_name CHECK (your_condition)
    ,CONSTRAINT constraint_2_name CHECK (your_condition_2)
    ...
     )
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Comment: @ lad2025 sir,Please can you help me once how to add same constraint at a time for more then one column (i.e col1,col2,col3 col4..) , logic same for all column

Comment: @PNayak Please see update answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `add` clause doesn't have parenthesis. Remove them and you should be OK.

```
ALTER TABLE emp ADD CONSTRAINT CC_NAME 
-- "(" removed here-^
CHECK (TRIM(TRANSLATE(UPPER(ename), ' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_,.',' ')) IS NULL)
-- ")" removed here---------------------------------------------------------------^
ENABLE NOVALIDATE;
```